# AWS - Delete objects in S3 bucket older than 90 days using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to delete some files which are present in an S3 bucket using Ansible. I have the below code and i need to delete objects based on a condition, e.g. objects being older than 3 months.

```yaml
    - name: delete object from bucket which is older than 3 months
      aws_s3:
        encrypt: yes
        aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
        bucket: "{{ bucket }}" 
        prefix: "{{ database_name }}/"
        marker: "{{ database_name }}/"
        mode: delobj
        s3_url: "{{ s3_url}}"
        validate_certs: no
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most clean solution would be to let AWS do this for you. As you might know, you can [configure S3 lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html). You can let [Ansible configure a bucket with the s3_lifecycle module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/s3_lifecycle_module.html) as such:

```yaml
- name: Configure a lifecycle rule on a bucket to expire (delete) items with a prefix of /logs/ after 3 months
  community.aws.s3_lifecycle:
    name: mybucket
    expiration_days: 90
    prefix: logs/
    status: enabled
    state: present
```